# Save checkmark in NSUserDefaults - dynamic TableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, save, nsuserdefaults, checkmark

**Solution!!**

Thanks Josh for all the patience :D

So the code in the initial question always ticks the selected cell and deselects a previously selected cell without saving anything to the `NSUserDefaults`. After a lot of help from Josh the new code (right below) is the following (exactly the same as in his reply/I only clened it up a little and removed @properties defined in previous attempts to make it work).

The user taps one of the 7 cells. The indexPath of tapped cell is then saved in the `NSUserdefaults`and when the TableView is open again a checkmark is displayed next to the previously tapped cell. The indexpath is always saved in the same `NSObject`so only one checkmark will ever be displayed.

```html
#import "CycleTableViewController.h"
#import "SettingsTableViewController.h"

@interface CycleTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) int selectedRow;
@end

@implementation CycleTableViewController
@synthesize array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    //load array containing options
    array=@[@"1", @"2",  @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    //save indexpath of tapped cell to NSUserdefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(indexPath.row) forKey:@"cycle"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
    }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIndentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   
    //display checkmark next to the tapped cell
    if(indexPath.row == self.selectedRow){
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    else{
       ell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }         
        return cell;
    }

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //assign indexpath to selectedRow, so NSUserdefaults can save them
    self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;        
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    //save indexpath of tapped cell to NSUserdefaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(indexPath.row) forKey:@"cycle"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

@end
```

---

**Initial question**

I've been reading through tons of posts on here on saving an index path to the user defaults, but none of them has worked for me...

In the following TableView I have an array of data (1-7) that is displayed and then passed to another ViewController once a cell is pressed. The pressed cell gets a checkmark and if I go back using the Navigation Controller I can see the checkmark. Only one item is selected at a time. If I press another row, the checkmark changes.

So now I want to save the indexpath of the selected row to the UserDefaults (in the `didselectrowat indexpath`) and the load it in the `viewdidload` but I always get a `build failed`, whatever I try...

Can somebody please point me in the right direction? This should be easy, but I somehow just can't get it to work :/

**Updated Code! Once I get it working I'll upload the finished answer!**

```html
#import "CycleTableViewController.h"
#import "SettingsTableViewController.h"


@interface CycleTableViewController (){
    NSString *currentCategory; // pointer to the currently checked item
}
// other @property declarations here or in your .m file
#define CHECKED_KEY @"kCheckedBoxKey"

@property (nonatomic) int selectedRow;



@end

@implementation CycleTableViewController
@synthesize array;



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    
    //load tickmark according to newCell;
    
    array=@[@"21+7", @"22+6",  @"23+5", @"24+4", @"25+3", @"26+2", @"28"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.selectedRow = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cycle"] intValue];
    
 }

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIndentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(indexPath.row) forKey:@"cycle"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    
    NSIndexPath *IndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.selectedRow inSection:0];
    UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:IndexPath];
    Cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import "CycleTableViewController.h"
#import "SettingsTableViewController.h"


@interface CycleTableViewController (){
    NSString *currentCategory; // pointer to the currently checked item
}
// other @property declarations here or in your .m file
#define CHECKED_KEY @"kCheckedBoxKey"

@property (nonatomic) int selectedRow;

@end

@implementation CycleTableViewController
@synthesize array;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    //load tickmark according to newCell;

    array=@[@"21+7", @"22+6",  @"23+5", @"24+4", @"25+3", @"26+2", @"28"];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.selectedRow = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"cycle"] intValue];        
 }

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(indexPath.row) forKey:@"cycle"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIndentifier=@"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if(indexPath.row == self.selectedRow){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
     }
    else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }         
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;        
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you Josh for all the patience and the huge help! It's finally working and your logic is obviously right. I've been refercing self.tableview as well to load the data... Thanks so much again, when I get to 15 points I'll declare your answer and give it a thumbs up :) Can't do that yet...

Answer (score 0):

Where in the code are you saving the user defaults?

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you could add:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@(indexPath.row) forKey:@"nameOfSetting"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can check if

```
indexPath.row == [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nameOfSetting"] intValue]
```

and if so, add the checkmark accessory.  If not, show no accessory.

Note that I would actually create a property that holds the selectedValue, and only upon leaving the settings page or tapping a save button do you actually update the user defaults.  Then in `viewWillAppear` I would set this property equal to the setting in the user defaults and call reload on the table.

**EDIT**
To expand on the final note, you can do the following:

In the interface...

```
@property (nonatomic) int selectedRow;
```

In the implementation...

```
self.selectedRow = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"nameOfsetting"] intValue];
```

You can place this code in `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear` or even in `prepareForSegue` in the previous view controller that you are segueing from as long as the selectedRow property is declared in the header file.  I would not put this code in `viewDidLoad`.

Then separately in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I would add something like:

```
if(indexPath.row == self.selectedRow){
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

**EDIT #2**

In the `OptionsViewController` where the current setting is displayed you can load the setting from standardUserDefaults.  You can save a number like I mentioned as the setting (i.e. if you have setting options, you can number them 0 - 6 and use a typedef to make the code more clear) or you can store a string.  If you store your setting as a number, you just need a dictionary to map the number to a setting description.  If you store your setting as a string, you could just display the string.

Regardless of the method chosen, in the `OptionsViewController` do this:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
   if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]]){
       SettingsViewController *settingsViewController = (SettingsViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
       settingsViewController.selectedSetting= <INSERT YOUR SETTING FROM STANDARDUSERDEFAULTS>
    }
 }
```

Basically, you are handing off your setting from the options to the settings view which contains your table.  You can make your `selectedSetting` in the `SettingsViewController` a number or a string as above.  Just as some point, you have to convert your setting into a number so that the table knows which row has the checkmark.  I would keep the rest of the code the same, i.e. the if statement in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  You need to somehow check if the indexPath.row matches the selectedSetting (i.e. if it is a string, you need to convert it into a number).  And in the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` reload the tableView so the checkmark will be displayed.

When the user selects a different row, you can update the selectedSetting property and then in `viewWillDisappear` or `prepareForSegue` (i.e. before the unwind segue) you can update standardUserDefaults.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Josh! What you have pasted in there is actually what I've been doing. But if I copy the first one into the `didselectrowatindexpath`to save the indexpath and the second one in the 'viewdidload` to load the checkmark I always get a undeclared identifier problem. I feel it's something super straightforward im ignoring :/ Would you load the path in the `cellForRowAtIndex` or in the `viewdidload`? and how would you exactly put it in there? About your last comment: I have a segue that I left out that automatically shows another viewcontroller.

Comment: What line of code is giving you the undeclared identifier error?  What is the specific method not declared?

Comment: Thank you very much for the extensive reply. Unfortunately I think I haven't comunicated my problem very well. I have a settingspage that opens the TableView containing 7 options and the code ticks the selected row when it's tapped, then closes the TableViewController and forwards the indexpath via a segue to the options page where its displayed. I want to save that tickmark (NSuserdefault in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), load it automatically when I open `tableview` again (e.g.from the viewdidlod) so the tick is displayed. Your code only checks if the tapped cell is equal to the saved row, no?

Comment: I added a second edit :).  The overall process is to have OptionsViewController load from standardUserDefaults every time it appears, hand off the current setting when it segues to the SettingsViewController, show a checkmark for the row corresponding to that specific setting, update standardUserDefaults when the setting has changed before unwinding back to the OptionsViewController.  When the OptionsViweController appears again, it will reload from standardUserDefaults and display the updated setting.

Comment: Haha Josh I think I'm testing your patience here... :O So I'm saving the indexpath in the `NSuserdefaults`upon selection and loading them in the OptionsViewController. This is working correctly. I'm still left with the tickmarks. I just need code to always select the cell at `self.selectedRow`. what I did above in `didselectrow`should do that no? But it's not ticking anything :/

Comment: No worries - I have a lot of patience :)  I am assuming that you were able to get self.selectedRow to be set by the OptionsViewController as it segued to the SettingsViewController.  Getting the UITableView to show one row with a checkmark and all the other rows without a checkmark is just an issue of display and it is handled solely by the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  As the tableView scrolls, it will dequeue cells as necessary and must set the accessory for each cell appropriately either to checkmark or none.  Did you try adding the if statement from Edit #1?

Comment: In addition, when you select a new row, in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you will need to do self.selectedRow = indexPath.row; And then add [tableView reloadData]; When the table reloads, it will reset all the accessories and only add a checkmark when the indexPath equals the new self.selectedRow.

Comment: Did you implement the IF statement shown above, right above **EDIT #2**?

Comment: Yeah I, did... It's all like you said... I posted my whole code (I added a second edit. I'd really appreciate it if you you take a second look...

Comment: I'll edit your code in another answer.  You are viewing the didSelectAtIndexPath method as a method that can be used to actually check the appropriate cell.  The problem with this line of thinking is that cells are reused in a table.  You never really know which cell will need to be checked.  Instead think of the didSelectAtIndexPath as a way to keep track of which setting was now selected.  The cellForRowAtIndexPath method will then determine, no matter which cell is being reused, whether or not the the cell should be checked or not based on the indexRow and the selected setting.

Comment: I referenced self.tableView in my code in order to reload the table.  Not sure if you have an outlet set up to your tableView, so you will need to add that.